# What kind of CCSID value can be used for WMQ QMGR?

Tags: ibm-mq, mq

The question is about **the value of ccsid from QMGR**. When doing this configuration, how many 
ones can be used in total? How do i know what kind of ccsid i'm able to choose from? Is there any way to find it out?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Accordint go IBM WebSphere MQ 7.0 Infocenter, the following applies to queue manager option CCSID (Coded Charset ID):

> The coded character set identifier for the queue manager. The CCSID is the identifier used with all character string fields defined by the API. It does not apply to application data carried in the text of messages unless the CCSID in the message descriptor is set to the value MQCCSI_Q_MGR when the message is put to a queue.
>
> Specify a value in the range **1 through 65 535**. The CCSID must specify a value that is defined for use on your platform, and use a character set that is appropriate to the platform.

I think the bold part answers the first part of your question (how many can be used), although it should be noted that you can only use one particular CCSID for your queue manager.

You can only use CCSIDs valid for your platform (you did not mention which OS the queue manager is running on). See [WebSphere MQ / Application Programming Reference / Code Page Conversions](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.mq.csqzak.doc/fr20890_.htm) for a list of supported conversions on a platform of your choice.